# Unable to capture image data using Windows Biometric Framework

Tags: java, c++, wbf

I am developing a Biometric module using WBF. I am using the code given at [Winbio CaptureSampleImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbiocapturesample) to get image data which is converted to a .bmp file and saved. I created a DLL file containing all the code related to my work with WBF. I am using this DLL in a Java Spring Boot Application using [JNI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html). The jar created by this is run via a .vbs file as given below.

```
Set shellObj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shellObj.ShellExecute "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe", "-jar MyApp.jar", "", "runas", 0
```

"runas" is used to run jar as Administrator rights. "0" is used to set it invisible.

I have previously used the DLL in a Jar running as a service using [WINSW](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw). For this I included [WinBio AcquireFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbioacquirefocus) after creating a session as mentioned in [WinBio AcquireFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbioacquirefocus) and [Winbio CaptureSampleImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbiocapturesample) and it works perfectly fine.

Now I have two scenerios.

**1)** I use the code provided in [Winbio CaptureSampleImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbiocapturesample). This approach gets stuck when following is called.

```
hr = WinBioCaptureSample(
            sessionHandle,
            WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE,
            WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW,
            &unitId,
            &sample,
            &sampleSize,
            &rejectDetail
            );
```

that is no output is returned.

**2)** I use [WinBio AcquireFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbioacquirefocus) like I did with my service.

This prompts error:

> Code : 0x80070005 (Access Denied).

Common HRESULT values are given [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values). This is probably because AcquireFocus can not be used in Application such as mine.

Comment: Trying to push the community for "urgent" help will have the exact opposite of the indented effect.

Comment: Ehh sorry about that.

Comment: From what I can see - you've been asking the microsoft support group for help - they seem to be the group that would know the most

Comment: Ill ask there too.